# A View in ConstraintLayout not being placed as expected when app is made run in device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout to create a view that is to be used in RecyclerView.
For some reason, one TextView is taking unexpected place when I am installing an app in the device.
Below is the view that is being used in RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="31-Jan"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:10 PM"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewReason"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Reason"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewReason"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewReason" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the activity that contains RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTransactionList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The view in question is textView2. It takes a proper place in the editor (at the end of parent with 8dp padding). But when I install the apk, it shifts in left.
Also, I have used below written code to populate RecyclerView:

```
TransactionRecyclerViewAdapter transactionRecyclerViewAdapter = new TransactionRecyclerViewAdapter(transactionList);
    LinearLayoutManager l = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
    recyclerViewTransactionList.setAdapter(transactionRecyclerViewAdapter);
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerViewTransactionList.setLayoutManager(l);
```

Here are editor and device screenshot:
[image: The editor image]

[image: This is rendered image]

Comment: please share image

Comment: here they are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was somewhere else.
In the method onCreateViewHolder, while inflating the layout, I was not sending appropriate parameters to the inflate() method:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_oneday_expanse_view, null);
```

The problem got solved when I changed the passing arguments to these:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_oneday_expanse_view,parent, false);
```

I am not sure why this happens. Will appreciate if someone can explain it.
Thanks everyone for answering!

Comment: Since you weren't sending a parent view with the `LayoutInflator` the `match_parent` constraint wasn't working on the root view of the item layout

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in here:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewReason"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewReason"
```

Where you are trying to use `constraintTop` and `constraintBottom` in a same view.

Comment: @TarunBaria Could you give me a sample of your desire output?

Comment: the problem got solved. I have ticked the right answer. basically, I wanted one textView to be on the right side of the screen, which was slipping down to the left side it is seen in the picture. thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Change** Your last text view of recycler view layout to this. I guess the problem is here.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Or you can try changing the Constraint layout to any other layout Like LinearLayout or Relative. Sometimes constraint layout gives a problem with recycler view.

Comment: Then change the constrainLayout.There is some problem with constraint layout while using it in the recycler sometimes. Once I had a problem with the same. I changed it to linear. This will work. Or you can try with the relative.

Comment: I tried this too. Relative was working. But then the solution that I have written below worked for ContstraintLayout too. Not sure about the reason behind it but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textViewReason" />
```

Ideally you just need to constraint the base line if you want it to align with the reason textView

Comment: Yeah you are right. But it didn't solve the problem. Thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with your `RecyclerView` constraints. It is not recommended to use `match_parent` for `Views` contained in a `ConstraintLayout` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout). The proper horizontal constraints for the `RecyclerView` should look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTransactionList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below mentioned code for your RecyclerView:

(as when using ConstraintLayout one must not use "match_parent" instead "match_constraint" is to be used whose value is equivalent to "0dp").

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTransactionList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

And also, try the below mentioned code for your "textView2" in the view that is being used for the RecyclerView purpose:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textViewReason"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewReason"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewReason"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
```

Hope this helps you. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't solve the issue but increased my knowledge about ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Try changing the dependency of the ConstraintLayout from 1.0.2 to 1.1.2 as 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'. It might work for you. Thanks for replying.